Code in codeMirror editor does not persist after page reload, despite using localStorage
I am building a code editor using React where users can write HTML, CSS, and JS. The output is displayed in an iframe, and the editor is implemented using CodeMirror. I want the code in the editor to persist even after the page reloads, and the iframe should reflect the latest changes. However, when I reload the page, the iframe shows the output correctly, but the code inside the editor is lost
What i did
I used localStorage to store the code every time it changes.
I used useEffect to load the saved code from localStorage when the component mounts.
I also tried to update the iframe with the new code every time the code in the editor changes.
Code
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Editor.css';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/mode/xml/xml';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
import 'codemirror/mode/css/css';
import { Controlled as ControlledEditor } from 'react-codemirror2';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCompressAlt, faExpandAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

function Editor(props) {
    const { language, displayName, value, onChange } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

    const handleChange = (editor, data, newValue) => {
        onChange(newValue);  
    };

    return (
        <div className={`Editor_Main ${open ? '' : 'collapsed'}`}>
            <div className="top">
                <span>{displayName}</span>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className="expand-collapse-btn"
                    onClick={() => setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)}
                >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={open ? faCompressAlt : faExpandAlt} />
                </button>
            </div>
            <ControlledEditor
                onBeforeChange={handleChange}  // Use onChange to handle value changes
                value={value}  // Set the value as the local state (editorValue)
                className="code-mirror-wrapper"
                options={{
                    lineWrapping: true,
                    lint: true,
                    mode: language,
                    theme: 'material',
                    lineNumbers: true,
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default React.memo(Editor);

What I expected:
When I reload the page, the code inside the editor should be loaded from localStorage and displayed.
The iframe should show the output based on the current code in the editor, which reflects the saved code from localStorage.what is the issue ?
